# iBeacon:CBPeripheralManager: 0x1557b230 can only accept this command while in the powered on state

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I have a 4s device with iOS 7.1. I'm trying to implement some code that helps my device to behave like a beacon device but I'm getting the error "can only accept this command while in the powered on state".

I am implementing this piece of code:

```
@implementation ViewController


-(void)viewDidLoad 
{


    [super viewDidLoad];
    beaconPeripheralData=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
     peripheralManager.delegate=self;
    _locationManager.delegate=self;
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self initWithBeacons];

}

-(void)initWithBeacons

{


    NSNumber * power = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-63];
    NSUUID *uuid=[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"F24BDBE3-EB98-4A04-A621-91C088DC32D2"];

    CLBeaconRegion *beaconReason=[[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:1 identifier:@"blackbean.com"];

    beaconPeripheralData=[beaconReason peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:power];

peripheralManager=[[CBPeripheralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

 [peripheralManager startAdvertising:beaconPeripheralData];

    if ([peripheralManager isAdvertising])
    {

        NSLog(@"peripeheralMAnager is advertising");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"peripeheralMAnager is not  advertising");
    }

}

-(void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {


    switch (peripheral.state) {
        case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            NSLog(@"Powered on");
            [peripheralManager startAdvertising:beaconPeripheralData];
            break;
        case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            NSLog(@"Powered Off");
            [peripheralManager stopAdvertising];
            break;
        case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported:
            NSLog(@"Device not supported");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [CBPeripheralManager documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015-CH1-SW20)

> Before you call CBPeripheralManager methods, the state of the
>   peripheral manager object must be powered on, as indicated by the
>   `CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn`. This state indicates that the
>   peripheral device (your iPhone or iPad, for instance) supports
>   Bluetooth low energy and that its Bluetooth is on and available to
>   use.

In order to determine when the peripheral manager is ready, you need to implement the [`didUpdateState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBPeripheralManagerDelegate/peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:) peripheral manager delegate method and start advertising once you get the powered on state, which you have done, but you also have a call to `startAdvertising` straight after you have allocated the `CBPeripheralManager`, which gives you the error message, because it won't yet be in the powered on state

Comment: Thannk You.! But i m confused where should i call the CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn.

Comment: should i used it as                                                                                              if(CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
         [peripheralManager startAdvertising:beaconPeripheralData];
    }
else
{
    
}

Comment: You don't call it, you check for it.  You already have the right code in the delegate method - `switch (peripheral.state) {
        case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn:` but you need to delete the line `[peripheralManager startAdvertising:beaconPeripheralData];` straight after  `peripheralManager=[[CBPeripheralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];`

Comment: after emtering in -(void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral   controll reached to the last case statement instead   CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn statement..plz help

Comment: the `default` case or the `unsupported` case?  You can expect this delegate method to be called multiple times.

Comment: unsupported case  get called

Comment: is there any issue in my device and ios that i m using.??

Comment: If it is a 4S and not a 4 then BLE is supported. You can try turning it off and on again

Answer (score 2):

I was following Apple's official [Turning an iOS Device into an iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/turning_an_ios_device_into_an_ibeacon) article, and it states to use the following code:

```
func advertiseDevice(region : CLBeaconRegion) {
    let peripheral = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    let peripheralData = region.peripheralData(withMeasuredPower: nil)

    peripheral.startAdvertising(((peripheralData as NSDictionary) as! [String : Any]))
}
```

However, the last line causes the "can only accept this command while in the powered on state" error.

To fix it, I had to:

- Store a strong reference to the CBPeripheralManager so that it doesn't get deallocated.
- Listen for the didUpdateState method, and only when it is `poweredOn` call the startAdvertising method.
- Use a real iPhone to advertise. If you attempt to use the simulator, you'll get CBManagerState `unsupported`.

Here's an example of what the advertising code needs to look like to avoid this error instead of Apple's example:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
  var manager: CBPeripheralManager?

  func advertiseDevice() {
    self.manager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
  }
}

extension Foo: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

  func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    notifyOfStatusChange("iBeacon advertiser state change: \(peripheral.state.rawValue)")
    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
      let region = createBeaconRegion()!
      let peripheralData = region.peripheralData(withMeasuredPower: nil)
      peripheral.startAdvertising(((peripheralData as NSDictionary) as! [String : Any]))
    }
  }
}
```